# Azure Resource Project Set CNAME for WebApp

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I am looking for any information about putting my custom domain (in my case CNAME) in Azure Resource Project in template which contains WebApp.

Could anyone have any knowledge about that? ad could share it with others?

Answer (score 0):

Update the Microsoft.Web/Sites section to look something like this:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
    "type": "hostNameBindings",
    "name": "www.yourcustomdomain.com",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webAppName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "domainId": null,
        "hostNameType": "Verified",
        "siteName": "variables('webAppName')"
    }
}
```

ref: https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/app-service-web-arm-with-msdeploy-provision.md#create-arm-template